# Solving $u'+tu^2=0$ by integrating factor

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I need to solve $u'+tu^2=0$, so I did:

$$\phi(t)u'+\phi(t)tu^2 = 0$$

we must have $\phi'(t) = t\phi(t)\implies \phi(t) = e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}$

So our equation becomes:

$$(e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}u^2)'=0\implies e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}u^2 = c_1 \implies u = \sqrt{\frac{c}{e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}}}$$

but this is not the answer. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why do you need the integrating factor? this is a separable equation. Also, integrating factor is not applied the way you have done even if it was applicable here.

Comment: @Chinny84 I know it can be done as an exact. But why integrating factor won't work here?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the method of integrating factors isn't applicable to non-linear ODEs like this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}u^2\right)=te^{\frac{t^2}{2}}u+2e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}uu'=e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}u(t+2u')=e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}u\left(t-2\frac{u^2}{t}\right).$$ There is no reason for being equal to zero.

If you had to solve $u'+tu=0$ the situation would be different. Note that

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}u\right)=te^{\frac{t^2}{2}}u+e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}u'=e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}(tu+u')=e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}0=0.$$

What is the difference? The second one is a linear ODE while the first not. (See the comment by @Michael Seifert).